# Using AWS CodeBuild with SVN Repository Timeout/Stalling Issue

Tags: tortoisesvn, aws-codebuild

I have an AWS codebuild project and a an svn repository which contains the java code I need to build. For my codebuild configuration, I chose **No Source** Type and am using a windows container. During the Install event I am downloading a tortoisesvn msi and installing tortoisesvn on my container. I then make a svn checkout call to my svn. It is a pretty large repo that I am checking out and at first, it continued to timeout on me with error **svn: E175012: Connection timed out**. I solved this by adding the option **servers:global:http-timeout=2400** to lengthen the time for an svn checkout before the server times it out. However, now the checkout just stalls at a certain point in the checkout command output after some arbitrary amount of time. Eventually the timeout on the codebuild project times the project out. I have set svn timeout to 40 min as shown above and codebuild timeout to 1.5 hours but have had no luck in completing the checkout and building the code. Unfortunately, codebuild does not provide much visibility into the windows container used to build my code so I am unsure what to try next. Any advice would be appreciated. Below is the relevant portion of my buildspec.

```
TORTOISE_URL: 'https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/osdn/storage/g/t/to/tortoisesvn/1.13.1/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.13.1.28686-x64-svn-1.13.0.msi'
TORTOISE_INSTALL: 'C:\TortoiseSVN-1.13.1.28686-x64-svn-1.13.0.msi'


install:
    commands:
      - '[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; Invoke-WebRequest $env:TORTOISE_URL -OutFile $env:TORTOISE_INSTALL'
      - msiexec.exe /i $env:TORTOISE_INSTALL /passive /norestart ADDLOCAL=ALL
      - $env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")
      - '& $env:TORTOISE_HOME/bin/svn checkout --username $env:SVN_USERNAME --password $env:SVN_PASSWORD $env:SVN_REPO/$env:SVN_TAG --config-option servers:global:http-timeout=2400'
```

Comment: Can you launch a Windows EC2 in default subnet with internet connectivity and run these commands there to find out if they actually work. Also see if there are any verbose options to these commands so you know whats going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have run the commands in a powershell shell on a windows ec2 with internet access and it checkouts the code completely. This suggests to me that it is somehow related to the time it takes to output the contents of the checkout to the codebuild logs. They are logged more slowly than they show up in the terminal of course. Also, I do not believe svn checkout has any verbose option, only a quiet option unfortunately.